# Module developement update composer config

Tags: magento2, module, development, composer

During module developement (module is palced in app/code) after adding new package to composer.json, how can i make magento to install that package ?

Comment: Did you try running `composer update` ?

Comment: i did it in root directory, did not worked

Answer (score 0):

You should install it by self using `composer require packet:version` from Magento root.